# Joomla Admin Menu disappered

Tags: joomla, admin

I have seen other posts but no answers, I have a Joomla 2.5 site that has lost the admin menu for the superuser (me), Mangers which have limited access and a cut down menu still have the menu How do I fix this so I can work on the web site?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to open: `/administrator/index.php?option=com_modules`

Select `Filter: Administrator` and check settings for module **Admin Menu**.

Hope this helps